# How to override an UserControl method in ascx file without a source?

Tags: c#, user-controls, asp.net-4.0, ascx

I have a control inherited from `UserControl`. This control has a `LinkButton` on it with `LbButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)` method. I have only an ascx file for this control and a precompiled assembly.

I need to replace `LbButtonClick` method with my own custom method. How to do this? Can I do this in the ascx file or do I have to modify the control when it is loaded for the first time on the webpage.

I would like to use a first solution if it is possible(ascx file)  - to keep my modification as close as possible to the control itself.

**Edited**

I wanted to thank @pid and @Francesco Milani for their help. I was considering their solutions but before implementing them I just tried one more thing.. Simply I've added this code in ascx file of the mentioned control.

```
<script runat="server" type="text/C#">
    protected void LbButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Some code here...
    }
</script>
```

And it worked. It seems that redefining method in ascx file is allowed and this redefined method is called instead the one precompiled in assembly. I got no info from the compiler, no warning or hint. Quite strange, I do not get it. Since this is easier and cleaner than the proposed solutions I would accept it as an answer, but I do not like to accept my own answers.

Perhaps someone could explain me why the above construct worked?

Answer (score 0):

Never tried this but you should be able to derive from the class and then use that in the form. If the class is sealed... no dice!

Another way would be to wrap the ASCX around your own, remove the button from the original ASCX (by editing its HTML) and then add a button in your own. When your own button is clicked, fire the click event of the inner ASCX "manually": `LbButtonClick(mySender, myArgs)`.

I'm curious how this works out. Let us know how you solve this, please!

Comment: Hello, as you requested I am informing in my edited answer how I solved the problem. :) Sorry for the late answer, I had no time to write it earlier.

Comment: Your self-answer actually is very interesting. +1 for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this.

testControl.acx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="testControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="TestWebApp.testControl" %>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

and codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.LinkButton1.Click += LinkButton1_Click;
}

private void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
}
```

In your example you don't have access to LinkButton1_Click method.. so

default.aspx

```
<%@ Register Src="~/testControl.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="testControl" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <uc1:testControl runat="server" id="testControl" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and codebehind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (LinkButton lb in testControl.Controls)
        {
            if (lb.ID == "LinkButton1")
            lb.Click += lb_Click;
        }
    }

    private void lb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("http://www.microsoft.com");
    }
```

So you will be redirect to microsoft instead of google.
Hope it helps